# Spring Cloud Gateway POST Forbidden

Tags: spring-security, cross-domain, csrf, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a resource service behind Cloud Gateway route with RelayToken filter:

```
      routes:
        - id: apis
          uri: http://rest-app:8080/apis
          predicates:
            - Path=/apis/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
```

GET requests work fine, but on POSTs I get 403 Forbidden with response body containing
`CSRF Token has been associated to this client`
I've tried to disable CSRF protection adding `Bean`

```
@Bean
fun springWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    return http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().build()
}
```

But this has no effect and I still get 403. Moreover I cannot debug which exactly filter prevents client from doing POST requests, the only logging information I get with

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: TRACE
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
    org.springframework.security.oauth2: TRACE
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: TRACE
    org.springframework.security.jwt: TRACE
```

is just couple of lines saying POST was forbidden

```
[2020-04-01 13:21:32,635] TRACE o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter  - [58a0e540-10] HTTP POST "/apis/", headers={masked} 
[2020-04-01 13:21:32,640] TRACE o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter  - [58a0e540-10] Completed 403 FORBIDDEN, headers={masked} 
[2020-04-01 13:21:32,640] TRACE o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter  - [58a0e540-10] Handling completed
```

How do I correctly turn CSRF off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct SecurityWebFilterChain that solved my problem:

```
@Bean
fun springWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    return http
        .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .build()
}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. my gateway will not do login but will expect consumer to send Bearer jwt token in request. http.csrf.disable() is working for me in eclipse (http) but when same application is deployed in ocp4/docker (https) it solution does not work.

Comment: Hi @DDD : Did you find any solution to this issue ?