# Spring Cloud Gateway POST Forbidden with CSRF enable

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, csrf, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-security

I want to enable CSRF in Spring Cloud Gateway with webflux. I have minimum configuration for that as described in link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/protection-against-exploits-2.html#webflux-csrf-configure

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain SecurityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    SecurityWebFilterChain SecurityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .oauth2Login().and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and().build();
    }    }
}
```

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SecurityControllerAdvice {
    @ModelAttribute
    Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken = exchange.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        return csrfToken.doOnSuccess(token -> exchange.getAttributes()
                .put(CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.DEFAULT_CSRF_ATTR_NAME, token));
    }
}
```

However, I am still getting 403 on POST along with body:
**CSRF Token has been associated to this client**

Can anyone pls help on this?

PS: In these questions CSRF has been disabled by user where same error is coming, but I need to keep it enabled:

[CSRF token has been associated to this client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66721649/csrf-token-has-been-associated-to-this-client)

[Spring Cloud Gateway POST Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971877/spring-cloud-gateway-post-forbidden)

Comment: Can you share did you managed to find a solution, please?

Comment: @user1285928 not yet!